# update mergetags_list after TinyMCE has been initialized

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

The documentation for https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/mergetags/#mergetags_list only defines the merge tags at the time TinyMCE is initialized. Are there any examples on how to update the list after initialization?

Called tinymce.init() using the same selector with a different merge tag list. Unfortunately, it did not update.

Answer (score 1):

Options configured in `tinymce.init()`, including `mergetags_list`, cannot be changed after the editor is initialized. You can only change the init config options by reinitializing the editor with [remove()](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#remove) and then [init()](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.root/#init).

See example fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/muiaab/5

Reinitializing will cause a flicker as the editor is removed and initialized. This flicker could be mitigated by using a "loading" overlay.  It should also be noted that reinitializing the editor will cause a side effect of losing the undo history.